# Is this the correct translation of what Tomoko is saying?

Tags: watamote

In *Watamote* Episode 10, Tomoko comes back to school to find out that her seat has been changed, she gets a little agitated and says this (well according to the subs, that is):

> I have to sit here for the whole goddamn second term? Fuck me with a chainsaw dildo!

Now, I can't really Read/Write Japanese or even understand it, but I'm not quite sure that she is actually saying that. ***Is she?***

[image: Fuck me with a chainsaw dildo]

Comment: I think it wasn't literally that, but possibly some other popular slang phrase meaning essentially the same thing − *very negative reaction*.

Comment: If you can find the Japanese that she's saying, someone is more likely to help you, rather than if they have to go find it and translate it themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Japanese is:

> ニ学期ずっとこの席だと？ストレスで胃が蜂の巣になる！

More or less literally,

> I have to sit here for all of second term? The stress will turn my stomach into a beehive [i.e. thing with many holes]!

The subtitles you have there are from [Commie]; their subtitles for Watamote were edited by one of their more, um, liberal editors.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [there's a version on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmtkbo2QJ7Y) floating around of that very opening...I doubt that.

While I don't speak fluent Japanese, it's pretty clear that the word "stress" as well as the word for "stomach" are said, so the above video is likely closer to reality.

But that picture?  Not a chance.  It was probably a liberty taken on part of the translator to include some emphasis of the situation.